# My Pygame Character Is Not Moving Continuously

Tags: python, pygame

Actually i am building a game in pygame called Alien invasion in which a ship fires bullets to aliens. I am at early stage of the game but i have a problem here .My game was working properly when i did not add continuous movement but now it is not moving as i expected!

I HAVE THREE FILES OF PYTHON:

1: aline_invasion.py

```
import pygame
import sys
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship


class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to control game assets and behaviour"""

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.setting = Settings()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.setting.screen_width, self.setting.screen_height))
        self.title = self.setting.game_title
        self.ship = Ship(self)


    def run_game(self):
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self.ship.update()
            self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.ship.moving_right = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.ship.moving_left = True

            elif event.type == pygame.K_UP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.ship.moving_right = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.ship.moving_left = False

    def _update_screen(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.setting.bg_color)
        self.ship.blit_me()

        pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

2: settings.py

```
import pygame


class Settings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_width = 900
        self.screen_height = 600
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
        self.game_title = pygame.display.set_caption('Alien Invasion')
```

3: ship.py

```
import pygame


class Ship:
    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False

        # Load the ship image and get its rect
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen.
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

    def update(self):
        if self.moving_right:
            self.rect.x += 1
        if self.moving_left:
            self.rect.x -= 1

    def blit_me(self):
        # Draw the ship at its current location
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem, but in function `_check_events` change `elif event.type == pygame.K_UP:` into `elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:`, see if it solves the problem

Comment: ... `pygame.K_UP` is the enumerator constant for the upwards key. The enumerator constant for releasing a key is `pygame.KEYUP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now I would suggest changing the way of registering button presses (I cannot tell if it is better but someone had similar problem and it helped him):

```
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
        
    
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_q]:
        # [...]
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        # [...]
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        # [...]
```

and so on